# run scheduler in background, stop process upon stop button using Python

Tags: python, selenium, pyqt5, background-process

i need to run process as background task & stop as user click stop button(terminate loop which actually runs on background) as process is in progress stop button couldn't be clicked that's why process can't be killed.moreover, i need to run this in single thread (currently it creates multiple windows) need to create only one process in which window open & perform its execution this function will continue unless user press stop button

```
import json
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPalette, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import xlrd as xlrd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import threading
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = "driver/chromedriver"
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = "driver/chromedriver"


def from_browser():
    chromeoptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chromeoptions.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
    chromeoptions.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chromeoptions.add_argument('--shm-size=2g')
    chromeoptions.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chromeoptions.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=chromeoptions)
    return browser


def Login():  # username,password):
    loc = ("List.xlsx")
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

    index = 1
    row = sheet.row_values(index)
    user_name = row[0]
    password = row[1]
    print(user_name)
    print(password)
    browser = from_browser()
    browser.implicitly_wait(10)
    browser.get("https://www.homeworkmarket.com/teacher-login")
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/form/div[1]/input").send_keys(user_name)
    time.sleep(1)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/form/div[2]/input").send_keys(password)
    time.sleep(1)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/form/button").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    return browser


def main():
    link_list = []
    browser = Login()
    browser.get("https://www.homeworkmarket.com/api/questions?offset=0&limit=7")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser').text
    # print(soup.text)
    rem = soup.replace('\n', '')
    load = json.loads(rem)
    for data in load['data']:
        title = data['path']['path']
        link_list.append("https://www.homeworkmarket.com" + str(title))
    return link_list, browser


def single_bid_fun(single_bid, browser):
    browser.get(single_bid)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser').text
    rem = soup.replace('\n', '')
    load = json.loads(rem)
    username = load['question']['user']['username']
    anchor = load['question']['fieldOfStudy']['anchor']
    budget = load['question']['budget']
    print(budget)
    divide = budget / 2
    print(divide)
    bid_dic = {
        "username": username,
        "anchor": anchor,
        "divide": divide
    }
    return bid_dic


def send_perposal(browser, perposal, price):
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#main-question > button").click()
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
        "body > div:nth-child(6) > div > div > form > div.css-17vsaq9 > div:nth-child(1) > input").send_keys(
        Keys.CONTROL + "a")
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
        "body > div:nth-child(6) > div > div > form > div.css-17vsaq9 > div:nth-child(1) > input").send_keys(
        Keys.DELETE)
    time.sleep(1)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
        "body > div:nth-child(6) > div > div > form > div.css-17vsaq9 > div:nth-child(1) > input").send_keys(str(price))
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
        "body > div:nth-child(6) > div > div > form > div.css-17vsaq9 > div:nth-child(2) > input").send_keys(
        Keys.CONTROL + "a")
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
        "body > div:nth-child(6) > div > div > form > div.css-17vsaq9 > div:nth-child(2) > input").send_keys(
        Keys.DELETE)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
        "body > div:nth-child(6) > div > div > form > div.css-17vsaq9 > div:nth-child(2) > input").send_keys(
        str(price), )
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
        "body > div:nth-child(6) > div > div > form > div.css-17vsaq9 > div.css-1xn3edc > div > textarea").send_keys(
        str(perposal))
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div:nth-child(6) > div > div > form > input").click()
    time.sleep(1)


# hassan code
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Homework Market')
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint, False)
        # self.setStyleSheet()
        self.setGeometry(100, 200, 300, 200)
        self.process_start = True

        # add background image & styles for window layout
        oImage = QImage("background.jpg")
        sImage = oImage.scaled(QSize(500, 300))  # resize Image to widgets size
        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.Window, QBrush(sImage))
        self.setPalette(palette)
        self.label = QLabel('Homework Market', self)  # test, if it's really backgroundimage
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: white; font-size: 22px")
        self.label.setGeometry(55, 20, 200, 50)

        # creating drop down menu
        wid = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(wid)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.cb = QComboBox()
        self.cb.addItem("Select Budget Limit")
        self.cb.addItems(["$1", "$5", "$10", "$15", "$20", "$30", "$40", "$50", "$60", "$70"])
        self.cb.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selectionchange)
        self.cb.setStyleSheet("width:100%;height:20%")
        self.cb.setGeometry(100, 50, 150, 40)
        layout.addWidget(self.cb)
        wid.setLayout(layout)

        # creating a start button
        start_button = QPushButton("Start", self)
        start_button.setGeometry(50, 120, 80, 40)
        start_button.setStyleSheet("background-color : rgb(0, 170, 255);color: rgb(255, 255, 255);font-weight:bold")
        start_button.clicked.connect(self.start_enabled)

        # creating a stop button
        cancel_button = QPushButton("Stop", self)
        cancel_button.setGeometry(140, 120, 80, 40)
        cancel_button.setStyleSheet("background-color : rgb(255, 64, 16);color: rgb(255, 255, 255);font-weight:bold")
        cancel_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.stop_enabled("stop"))

        self.show()

    def selectionchange(self, i):
        print("Current index", i, "selection changed ", self.cb.currentText())

    # action method
    def start_enabled(self):
        while self.process_start and self.stop_enabled:
            threading.Thread(target=self.hit_and_check).start()
            continue

    def stop_enabled(self, process):
        if process != 'stop':
            return True
        print('button stop call')
        self.process_start = False
        sys.exit()

    def hit_and_check(self):
        if self.process_start and self.stop_enabled:
            list, browser = main()
            for link in list:
                try:
                    split_single_bid = link.split("https://www.homeworkmarket.com/questions/")[1]
                    single_bid = "https://www.homeworkmarket.com/api/object?path=%2Fquestions%2F" + split_single_bid
                    message = single_bid_fun(single_bid, browser)
                    browser.implicitly_wait(15)
                    browser.get(link)
                    # check_bid=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main-question']/a/span").text
                    check_bid = browser.find_element_by_class_name("css-10op2pj").text
                    # check_bid=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#main-question > button").text
                    time.sleep(1)
                    if check_bid == "Place bid!":
                        fin = open("message", "r")
                        file_text = fin.read()
                        perposal = file_text.replace("{username}", message['username']).replace("{FIELD}",
                                                                                                message['anchor'])
                        # print(perposal)
                        fin.close()
                        price = str(message['divide'])
                        send_perposal(browser, perposal, price)
                        print("======================================")
                        pass
                    else:
                        print("hre ")
                        browser.quit()
                        # break
                except:
                    pass
            browser.quit()
        else:
            sys.exit()


# Ends

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    oMainwindow = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Would you be able to write what the problem is you're experiencing?   Expected behaviour and error?

Comment: i'm facing this problem as user clicks start button process start , this process is handle by While loop as condition is true it creates multiple windows meanwhile if user click stop button it not even bother it that's why process couldn't be stopped

Comment: Hi Muhammed, it's unlikely someone is going to debug your whole application. Questions work best when they're focused on a single problem without an extra hundred lines of code diluting the challenge. Do you think you could have a go at creating a minimum reproducible example of your issue?  See here fir info -  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example